# Julia's Python performance example in pypy

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, pypy, julia

[Julia](http://julialang.org/) is a new statistical programming language that claims significantly better performance than competing languages.  I'm trying to verify this.  Julia has a performance test written in Python:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/test/perf/perf.py

I can't get it to work with pypy.  Perhaps this is due to numpypy incompatibilities with numpy, but I'm not getting far enough to determine that.  I followed the ImportError advice `"...or just write 'import numpypy' first in your program..."` but I get another ImportError: `"No module named numpy.linalg"`

I have near zero experience with Python and I'm looking for a complete solution that I can run.  The benefit of getting this to work is that we can we have a apples-to-apples (jit lang-to-jit lang) comparison.

Comment: It means that it finds numpy but not numpy.lingalg, but has numpy module module. It is most likely an install problem or version compatibility difference or numpy incompatibilities. I suggest you directly contact Numpy PyPy implementation authors. Full code and full tracebacks for the errors would be very useful to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not certain I have Numpy pypy installed.  I cloned the repo and tried running setup.py in root and in /core.  in root I'm told that I'm running the wrong setup.  in core I get an ImportError: No module named genapi.  I tried to install the module via pip but it could not be found.

Comment: I would love to see this comparison if someone can get it to work.

Comment: See http://buildbot.pypy.org/numpy-status/latest.html, linalg is not supported ATM. @StefanKarpinski: would you be interested in a rewrite to get it working with whatever PyPy supports today? BTW, here's the RFE in their tracker: https://bugs.pypy.org/issue915

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linalg is not implemented as of now. I think a new ffi and getting 1.9 out of the door (which require quite a few numpy fixes, see the bug tracker) are getting top priority. I don't think having linalg *right now* is that interesting. We would like to have more of numpy running first. I'm open to be convinced though. Arguments?

Comment: I cannot argue that my curiosity about pypy v. julia is higher priority than what you already have scheduled =)  Maybe others are blocked by linalg and can chime in.  Or per @TryPyPy suggestion the julia perf code can be re-written with whatever PyPy supports today

Comment: it's slightly more compelx. PyPy numpy support is not only unfinished, but also the performance is not completely what I would like it to be. So even if you can run the benchmarks, it's not clear to me I would be happy (now) with the results. So it's a bit complicated process overall :)

Answer (score 27):

[image: Test of python and julia performance]

There are 4 test on Julia git (perf.py) in pure Python.
Here, I run, in the same computer, **perf.py** (only the pure Python test) and **perf.pl** for a apples-to-apples comparison.
I'm a little worried for Python/Pypy timing :/

And... Why

```
## fibonacci ##

def fib(n):
    if n<2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```

is slower in Pypy than in Python ?

---

I post this question in https://bugs.pypy.org/issue1344 [Pypy slower in recursion than Python2.7, Python3.2 and Julia]
I get the next answer:

> This is a situation where the warmup time is very significant (it tries to 
>   inline all the recursion), but once you warm it up it's actually very fast.

So, I do the text with different numbers of **n** for **fib(n)**. Indeed, Pypy comes faster than Python with a n > 30, but in recursion is slower than Julia:

[ En **bold** the faster python implementation ]

[image: Recursion in Pypy Python and Julia]

---

**Because are implemented with recursion, Quicksort and fib are slower in Pypy.**
**Julia seems to be faster than PyPy.**

Comment: Nice stuff, Diego. Although I'm not entirely sure how this translates as "Julia and PyPy have the same performance". This looks a lot like "Julia always wins and often by quite a lot" ;-)

Comment: I had tested a mathematic test by calculating factorial instead of fib. From this test, I got a result that CPython is a little faster than Pypy.  I don't really know why mathematical performance of CPython is better than Pypy.